# Adding a setState in onPressed is clearing my TextField (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

I have a problem on showing and hiding the password using iconbutton. At first I didn't add a controller in the Textfield and it functioned well, but after I add the controller for the TextField, when I press the icon button the textfield is being cleared out. I tried removing the setState on the onpressed, it does nothing and it does not clear the Textfield strong text

here's my code

```
class LoginState extends State<Login>{
  Icon visibilityIcon = Icon(Icons.visibility);
  bool isVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fieldWidth = 350.0;
    final TextEditingController password = new TextEditingController();
    final TextEditingController userName = new TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(child: Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,children: [
          Center(
            child: Container(
                height: 50.0,
                width: fieldWidth,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset(0.2, 0.6),
                  child:TextField(controller:userName,decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Username",),style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.grey[850]),),
                )
            ),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 80,
              width: fieldWidth,
              child: Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset(0.2, 0.6),
                  child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.centerRight,children: [TextField(controller: password,decoration: const InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),obscureText: !isVisible,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16,color: Colors.grey[850]),),
                    IconButton(icon: visibilityIcon,onPressed: (){
                      setState(() {
                        if(!isVisible)
                        {
                          // print(password.text);
                          // visibilityIcon = Icon(Icons.visibility);
                          // isVisible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                          // visibilityIcon = Icon(Icons.visibility_off);
                          // isVisible = false;
                        }
                      });
                    }
                      ,)],)
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Center(child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () => onPressedLogin(password.text,userName.text),
            color: Colors.grey[900],
            focusColor: Colors.grey[400],
            child: Container(
              width: fieldWidth-30,
              child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text("Login",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white60),),
                    Icon(Icons.login_outlined,color:Colors.white60 ,)
                  ]),),),)
        ],),)
    );

  }

  void onPressedLogin(String userName,String password){
    print(userName+" "+password);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new to flutter

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you create new TextEditingController() inside build method every time it rebuilds. To fix it, just move the controller outside of build method like this:

```
class _LoginState extends State<Login>{
  Icon visibilityIcon = Icon(Icons.visibility);
  bool isVisible = false;

  final TextEditingController password = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController userName = new TextEditingController();
```

Pls let me know it that helped you. Cheers

Comment: Wow you just saved me :D, BTW how do I set this to answered? I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: can't upvote you :( my reputation is too low, but yeah thanks :D

Comment: glad that helped :) you should be able to accept the answer with "check icon" uder upvote/downvote icons on left side. I would appreciate that. Thx